# ContextMenu uses incorrect cornerRadius even after specifying contentShape

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, contextmenu

```
struct CardView: View {
    private var name: String = "Random Name"
    private var color: Color = Color.red
    
    private var CardContent: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Text(name)
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .medium, design: .rounded))
                .frame(width: 110, height: 80, alignment: .top)
        }
        .padding(.top, 20)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 190, alignment: .top)
        .background(color)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        CardContent
            .contentShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30, style: .continuous))
            .contextMenu {
                Button(action:{}){
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        Text("Delete")
                    }
                }
        }
        .shadow(color: color.opacity(0.5), radius: 10, x: 10, y: 10)
    }
}
```

When I long-press, the View is clipped incorrectly:

[image]]

Also, why is the trashcan image not coloured red?

Is it a `ContextMexu` quirk?

Comment: I just copy/pasted your code into a new project and it works fine for me. I don't see those white corners in your linked image. This was on an iPhone 11 Simulator, what are you seeing this behaviour on?

Comment: @Magnas I am using an iPhone SE simulator

Comment: The same code runs perfectly on the SE for me too. The problem may lie in your additional code?

Comment: @Magnas there is nothing else, this is it. [link](https://imgur.com/a/09T5KAA)

Comment: @Magnas I am using Xcode Version 11.6 (11E708) on BigSur. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm testing on Xcode 12.0 beta 3 and using an iOS deployment target of 14.0.

Comment: Currently on old laptop Catalina 10.15.6. Will try on BigSur when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out iOS 13.6 simulator has this weird artefact
Switched to iOS 14 with Xcode 12 and the problem disappeared.